# Any way to hook into `register_shutdown_function` to override "header()" redirection?

Tags: php, hook

With `register_shutdown_function` we can hook our function when the "exit/die" happens. However, if the script is being exited with :

```
header("location: http://example.com");
exit;
```

in such cases, our  `register_shutdown_function` does no get fired, as redirection happens. So, my question is, is there any way to override/cancel redirection at all?  My purpose is to change redirection link or whatever I want.

Comment: The redirection is part of your PHP code, you can make it conditional.

Comment: _“in such cases, our register_shutdown_function does no get fired, as redirection happens”_ - are you saying what the manual says about `register_shutdown_function` was not actually true then? It clearly states, _“Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or exit() is called.”_

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no, it is not part of my app, that's why i say.